# Masonry items overlapping when containing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am using an AJAX request to append Masonry items which include images. The problem is that these items frequently overlap. I've tried adding `imagesLoaded` and I'm now using the following code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/rss/test.php',
    type: 'GET',
    //data: {token : "1"},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data)
    {
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $('#container').append(data);
            $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
        });
    },
    error: function()
    {
       alert("error");
    }
})
```

Any idea what might still be causing the problem?

### JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append elements to the container before waiting images to be loaded

```
$('#container').append(data);
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
        });
```